# R svyglm prediction with spline function

Tags: r, survey

I want to make predictions from an R survey glm object that contains a natural spline in the formula. take the example from the [survey package homepage](http://staff.washington.edu/tlumley/survey/example-regression.html):

```
library(survey)
data(api)
dclus2 <-svydesign(id=~dnum+snum, fpc=~fpc1+fpc2, data=apiclus2)
m <- svyglm(api00 ~ ell + meals + avg.ed, design = dclus2)
```

i changed the last variable to be avg.ed. Now I want to do the following:

```
m2 <- svyglm(api00 ~ ell + meals + ns(avg.ed,4), design = dclus2)
```

i.e. i want a cubic spline on avg.ed. I hit an error if I want to make a prediction from modle m2 on some new data:

```
n <- data.frame(meals=2,ell=2,avg.ed=3)
predict(m1,newdata=n,type="response")
predict(m2,newdata=n,type="response")    # error
```

it seems `predict.svyglm` does not understand that `ns` is what it is (i.e. an object of class "ns"), when making the prediction. From the source code it seems that it does

```
mm %*% coef(object)
```

(where `mm` is the model matrix) to obtain the prediction - it does not use `predict.glm`, and I suspect there's a good reason for it. Was just wondering if there is a clever fix for that before I start to hack around.
Thanks.

Comment: could you separate them before `predict.svyglm`? :)  `x <- apiclus2 ; x[ , paste0( 'avg.ed.ns' , 1:4 ) ] <- ns( x$avg.ed, 4 ) ; dclus2 <-svydesign(id=~dnum+snum, fpc=~fpc1+fpc2, data=x)`

Comment: bingo. Thanks! that was easy enough...

Comment: i'd like to accept the edits you were making but i says i need 2K reputation before I can do that.

Comment: Dear @FlorianOswald, I also want to know how to deal with this problem, could you please tell me how to do the following job. thanks